# Image_classification using resnet50 model with imagenet db with my custom labels

Tags: python-3.x, image, deep-learning, imagenet

I am working on image_classification problem(multi-class).
i am using resnet50 model( https://keras.io/applications/#classify-imagenet-classes-with-resnet50 ) along with pretrained db "imagenet" using keras

I am getting the the output labels for which the images i passed to the model.

But now, 
i have image data and label data with me of my own dataset.

When i pass the images to the resnet50 model it gives back the imagenet labels that are already trained. Now, here, i want the output as my own labels which is already in dataset instead of getting imagenet labels.

How to to fine tune labels in resnet50 model with imagenet db in keras

I have tried the resnet50 model alone and it works fine. but, how to change the output to my own labels instead of imagenet pre-trained labels.

```py
from keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.applications.resnet50 import preprocess_input, decode_predictions
import numpy as np
import os

model = ResNet50(weights='imagenet')

path='/Users/resnet-sample/'

img_path=os.listdir(path)
count=0
for i in img_path:
    img = image.load_img(path+i, target_size=(224, 224))
    x = image.img_to_array(img)
    x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
    x = preprocess_input(x)

    preds = model.predict(x)
    print('Predicted:', decode_predictions(preds, top=1)[0], i)
    count=count+1
print(preds)
```

example:

i have an elephant image in jpg format and label its as an 'elephant' in my dataset.

when i pass this image to resnet50 model which uses imagenet pre-trained db the output i received is 'African-Elephant'(imagenet-label).

So instead of getting imagenet label as output, i want to tune this as 'elephant' as label which is in my dataset.

So, not sure how to fine tune the last layers that gives output as my labels instead of imagenet labels.

Pelase help me on this.

Thanks,

Srknt73

Answer (score 0):

The `weights` argument should be either `None` (random initialization), `imagenet` (pre-training on ImageNet), or the path to the weights file to be loaded. So you give the path to the file containing the labels of your dataset